# Robolectric: test Cookies in HttpResponse

Tags: android, robolectric, android-testing

I'm using [Robolectric](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/) to test my Android application.
I'm trying write a test to verify that my Android app correctly receives cookies from a HttpResponse.
I tried a few options, but could't get it to work.

Here is what I try in the test:

```
BasicHeader responseHeader = new BasicHeader("Set-Cookie", "cookiename=value");
String responseBody = "OK"
int responseCode = 200;
HttpResponse httpResponse = new TestHttpResponse(responseCode, responseBody, responseHeader);
Robolectric.addPendingHttpResponse(httpResponse);
```

And this is what my Android app code looks like:

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(urlString);
// omitted: add username & password to request as urlencoded parameters
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
// ...
List<Cookie> cookies = client.getCookieStore().getCookies();
```

Other tests run fine, so I got Robolectric to work.
But the cookies list is always empty, although when I use the app with the (app engine) backend, it works fine.
However, I can get the urlencoded username & password from the HttpPost in the test, so the request does get handled, there just aren't any cookies.

Has anyone tried something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Place your Robolectric.addPendingHttpResponse(httpResponse); line before calling connection method of android.

It might work...